# DatetimeIndex with time part only: is it possible

Tags: python, pandas

I've stuck with such a problem.
I have a set of observation of passenger traffic. Data is stored in .xlsx file with the following structure: `date_of_observation, time, station_name, boarding, alighting.`

I wonder if it's possible to create Dataframe with DatetimeIndex from such data if I need only 'time' component of datetime. (No dublicates of time is presented in dataset).

The reason for this requirement is that I use specific logic based on circular time (for example, 23.00 < 0.00, but 0.01 < 0.02 when compared), so I don't want to convert them to datetime.

Comment: Would storing the time as a float suffice?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the way I'm doing things now. This question is more about pure interest:)

Comment: When trying to use `time` type as indexer, get: `TypeError: object of type 'datetime.time' has no len()`

Comment: Can you explain more about your circular time requirement? I wonder if it might be solvable with [indexer_between_time](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.indexer_between_time.html).

Comment: Well, for example: i have train that starts at 23:50 and get to the destination at 0:30. In this case 23:50 less of 0:30 (this is regular case, so I don't want to deal with date here). So, I have a method in my RailroadSchedule class which sorts this train schedules in a correct manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible, only with datetime or with float index.
However, variant offered by unutbu is very useful.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you do not need to reduce the DatetimeIndex to just a time. Instead, to select rows based solely on the time component, you could use [DataFrame.between_time](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html). For example,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N = 200
dti = pd.date_range('2000-1-1', freq='10T', periods=N)
df = pd.DataFrame({'station_name': np.random.choice(list('ABCDEFGHIJ'), size=N),
                   'boarding': np.arange(N)*10,
                   'alighting': np.arange(N)},
                  index=dti)
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
>>> print(df.head())

                     alighting  boarding station_name
2000-01-01 00:00:00          0         0            B
2000-01-01 00:10:00          1        10            I
2000-01-01 00:20:00          2        20            H
2000-01-01 00:30:00          3        30            C
2000-01-01 00:40:00          4        40            E
```

But you can select all the rows whose times are between `23:00` and `0:30` like this:

```
>>> print(df.between_time('23:00', '0:30'))
                     alighting  boarding station_name
2000-01-01 00:00:00          0         0            B
2000-01-01 00:10:00          1        10            I
2000-01-01 00:20:00          2        20            H
2000-01-01 00:30:00          3        30            C
2000-01-01 23:00:00        138      1380            D
2000-01-01 23:10:00        139      1390            E
2000-01-01 23:20:00        140      1400            A
2000-01-01 23:30:00        141      1410            D
2000-01-01 23:40:00        142      1420            E
2000-01-01 23:50:00        143      1430            B
2000-01-02 00:00:00        144      1440            B
2000-01-02 00:10:00        145      1450            I
2000-01-02 00:20:00        146      1460            F
2000-01-02 00:30:00        147      1470            C
```

Comment: +1 There's also `DataFrame.between_time`, which essentially does this without having to delve into the `Index` API.

Comment: @PhillipCloud: Thanks. That really simplifies the answer.